# How to pass data from fragment container activity to another activity

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am working on an android app to predict food items using tensorflow on android.I am following instructions and using code provided from [Google Codelab - Tensorflow for poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#0) .I have added an extra activity and made it MainActivity from which i will launch CameraActivity using FAB.What i want to do is to show the predictions which are shown in  a fragment Camera2BasicFragment running from activity CameraActivity into a toast on my MainActivity as soon as i press the back button on navbar.You can also find full code  from page 2 of the tutorial link.

**Camera2BasicFragment**

```
  private void showToast(final String text) {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(
          new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              textView.setText(text);
            }
          });
    }
  }
```

**CameraActivity.java**

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    if (null == savedInstanceState) {
      getFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
          .commit();
    }

  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
floatingActionButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO something when floating action menu third item clicked
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting correct you want to transfer data from **CameraActivity** to **MainActivity**

then you can use the intents.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO something when floating action menu third item clicked
            Intent i = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,MainActivity);
            i.putExtra("KEY","suggestionValue");
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
  }
```

and then on MainActivity you can receive it like this

```
{
  String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY");
}
```

and if you are interested in passing values in between the fragments then you can use the **Bundle**

```
Fragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

then in onCreate of the receiving fragment, you can call this

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
        int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

I hope this clears your doubt about passing values in android activities and fragments.
Read more about [Bundle & Parcel](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles.html)